# Defining module.links.action.yml with route parameters

Tags: 8, routes, navigation

How can I pass dynamically route parameters to module.links.action.yml?

**My code of module.links.action.yml:**

```
module.group_apply:
  route_name: module.group_apply
  title: 'Subscribe to group'
  weight: 0
  appears_on:
    - entity.node.canonical
```

**My code of module.routing.yml:**

```
module.group_apply:
  path: '/projects/{project}/usergroup/{group}/subscribe'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\SubscriptionController::subscribe'
    _title: 'Apply'
  options:
    parameters:
      project:
        type: entity:node
      group:
        type: entity:node
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**My subscibe function (actually):**

```
public function subscribe(NodeInterface $project, NodeInterface $group) {
    return array(
        '#markup' => 'HERE WE GO!',
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what are you trying to do?

Comment: /projects/{project}/ 
/projects/{project}/usergroup/{group}/ 
this pathes are node-views (contextual filtered by a node-id)

And I want to attach some functionality to the views as action links with the contextual attributes like:

http://www.url.com/projects/32/usergroup/45/subscribe

So that I can do some stuff with the information of 32 and 45 (two nodes)

Comment: This could work, if both routes, the appears_on and the target route have the same two parameters. But this is not what you have in the question.

Comment: Excuse me, my comment above is wrong. /project is a view -  /project/{project} is a node - /projects/{project}/usergroup/ is a view - /projects/{project}/usergroup/{group} is a node. And i want to insert that action link on the node page of /projects/{project}/usergroup/{group}.

Comment: yes, exactly, you can place on the page `/projects/{project}/usergroup/{group}` an action link for `/projects/{project}/usergroup/{group}/subscribe`, the target link will pick up the route parameters if they match

Comment: Thats interesting, because I get this error:
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("project", "group") to generate a URL for route "module.group_apply". in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 171 of /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).
That isn't the problem of the module.routing.yml, because I can navigate to /projects/{project}/usergroup/{group}/subscribe without errors. This error appears on the nodepage, where the link should appear.

Comment: so you still try to place the action link on the page `entity.node.canonical` = `/node/{node}`

Comment: Thats right, but the URL-Alias is: projects/[node:field_related_project:target_id]/user-groups/[node:nid]
And the link should only appear on Node-Pages of Type "Group". Not on the node pages of project or other node types.

Comment: you can't place a link action on an alias, only on routes, it would be no problem to define a route with the two parameters

Comment: I can. If I would append `route_parameters project: 12 group: 2` to module.links.action.yml. It would work. But then, these parameters are fixed - but I need these link parameters dynamically, based on url parameters.

Comment: I think you understand it now, alias != route, of course you can replace the missing parameters with fixed ones, but that's not the point

Comment: So it's right, that I've to define a route for the node "group"?
Like:
`module.group.canonical:
  path: '/projects/{project}/user-groups/{group}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: group.default
    _title: 'Node'
  options:
    parameters:
      project:
        type: entity:node
      group:
        type: entity:node
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'`
And then delete the url alias pattern for this nodetype?

Comment: yes, and a custom node view controller, or use {node} instead of {group}

Answer (score 2):

1、you can add class to process as follows：

[image]

2、you can debug in getRouteParameters function, localAction.php content as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was on the wrong track the whole time.

The right way is to use entity.node.canonical as route (/node/{node}) and using other variables from node itself in the subscribe function ($node).

Thank you @4k4 for your help.